# AppHarbor background worker, could not load file or assembly WebActivator Version=1.5.2.0

Tags: c#, console-application, appharbor

I am having a problem when publishing a console application to appharbor.

Error message:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WebActivator,
>   Version=1.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

I have tried to add  WebActivator, Version=1.5.2 through nuget and the reference is set copy local to true. I have also tried to change from .net 4.5 to 4.0.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem seems to be that one of my references to the console app was built with framework v 4.5. So it was working locally. Also check that you arent referencing to a MVC project which may have caused problem as well. So when I reference a pure class library framework 4.0 it seems to work. Hope this helps someone!